# How to get only keys and values from php array?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have a problem with PHP arrays that I can't seems to find a solutions for.

Im using a str_replace to search for an array of keys, and replace it with values from another array

Example:

```
$findkeys = array("Key1","Key2","Key3");
$newvalues = array("Value 1","Value 2","Value 3");
$NewVal = str_replace($findkeys, $$newvalues,  "Hello, here is Key1 used");
```

This set the value of $NewVal to "Hello, here is Value 1 used".

This is what I want

```
$Data = array("Key1"=>"Value1","Key2"=>"Value2","Key3"=>"Value3");
findkeys = ##Code to get all Keys into an array## Here!!
newvalues = ##Code to get all values into an array## Here!!
$NewVal = str_replace($findkeys, $$newvalues,  "Hello, here is Key1 used");
```

Can/How this be be done?

Comment: It's not clear what you want beyond a simple foreach with an if check on the keys.

Comment: Did you really write `$$newvalues`?

Comment: I think `strtr()` is the function you want. It will take an associative array and replace all the keys with their values.

Comment: You can get all the keys with `array_keys()`, and all the values with `array_values()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$Data = array("Key1"=>"Value1","Key2"=>"Value2","Key3"=>"Value3");
$NewVal = str_replace(array_keys($Data), array_values($Data),  "Hello, here is Key1 used");
```

`array_keys()` will return all of the keys of an array with numeric and sequential keys as an array.

`array_values()` will return all the values of an array with numeric and sequential keys as an array.